# Find out if any transition is in progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there anyway to find out if there currently is a transition running on my page? Not on a specific element but globally for the whole page?

Thanks

Comment: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-jquery-to-detect-when-css3-animations-and-transitions-end

Comment: I know this, but it helps me finding out if a transition ends, not if there is currently any transition in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see when a css transition has ended you can use `transitionend`.

> The transitionend event is fired when a CSS transition has completed.

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/transitionend

Where you can just use 'flags' to see when the animation has completed and when not. Here an example:

```
var AnimationComplete;

$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('green');
    AnimationComplete= false;
    console.log(AnimationComplete);
});

$("*").bind("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function() {
    AnimationComplete= true;
    alert('animate ended');
    console.log(AnimationComplete);    
    return false; /*Cancel any bubbling*/
});
```

I have to say it is a **BAD** *practice*  to use the `*` selector, as it will bind these event[**s**] to all the element. It is better to write your specific elements in there.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHvyL/1)

**Update**

So basically how you determ that a transition is in progress is when my 'flag' `AnimionComplete` is false.

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHvyL/3/)

Here can you see 3 different states: **start**, **in progress** and **end**.